# I've tried other solutions but am still getting this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python

This may be a simple question but I've tried other solutions that have been suggested on here and nothing is working.

Here is my file structure:

```
main_dir
|_ scripts
  |_ initialize_db.py
|_ src
  |_ models.py
  |_ __init__.py
```

My initialize_db.py file needs to import metadata and models from the models.py file. This is the import statement I'm using: `from src.models import metadata`

This is what my `__init__.py` looks like: `from . import models`

This is the error I'm getting: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The package `src` has to be in a directory on your search path, and `main_dir` won't be on your search path if `initialize_db.py` isn't *directly* in the directory. No matter how you execute the script, only `scripts` will be added implicitly to the search path. Really, you  probably don't want `src` to be a package at all; you want `models.py` to be a top-level module to be found by a command like `PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/to/src python scripts/initialize_db.py`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score -1):

This will fix your problem:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import os

FILE = Path(__file__).resolve()
ROOT = FILE.parents[1]  # root directory
if str(ROOT) not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(str(ROOT))  # add ROOT to PATH
ROOT = Path(os.path.relpath(ROOT, Path.cwd()))  # relative

from src import models
```